# Is it possible to generalise firebase authentication errors?

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I came across a document from firebase on how to generalise authentication error messages for ex - instead of "invalid password" to return something as "invalide credentials"

I can't seem to find that document now. I'm sure there is a way to do it because it's a bad idea to expose specific error messages on login especially in production.

Would love to know how to get it done, been at this for hours trying to figure it out. I should've bookmarked it :/